# Strange crash on Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: android, dalvik, crash-reports

We have an Android app that has been out for several years.  We recently got this message from a user.

"I have had excellent use of your app on my Tab 2 10.1 but when I moved to a Samsung Tab 3 10.1 I get a screen lock after a few seconds operation and then the app closes, thereby making it impossible to use."

I asked the user to send me a log file of the crash.  I didn't see any obvious crash indication, but I did see the following unusual Dalvik entries:

```
D/dalvikvm(10652): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v1, v3, (#12)
D/dalvikvm(10652): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v5, v7, (#8)
D/dalvikvm(10652): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v1, v3, (#12)
D/dalvikvm(10652): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v5, v7, (#8)
D/dalvikvm(10652): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v2, v3, (#8)
D/dalvikvm(10652): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v2, v3, (#8)
E/FlurryDataSender(10652): --onReport 0aaed6a1-d074-4f9c-8e96-d015a4c071e7 sent. HTTP response: 200 : OK
D/dalvikvm(10652): GC_EXPLICIT freed 679K, 23% free 7357K/9532K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 21ms
E/dalvikvm(10652): JIT_INFO: We cannot transfer from GP reg to XMM and vice versa
I/dalvikvm(10652): JIT_INFO: Unsupported bytecode if-lt
I/dalvikvm(10652): Could not compile trace for Lcom/southernstars/skysafari/Utility;createTextAtlasInfo, offset 443
I/dalvikvm(10652): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/dalvikvm(10652): JIT_INFO: Issues in trace  Lcom/southernstars/skysafari/Utility;createTextAtlasInfo, offset 443
E/dalvikvm(10652): The following issues were seen:
I/dalvikvm(10652):  Issue: Trace contains bytecode with no implementation
I/dalvikvm(10652):  Issue: Issue registerizing the trace in the backend
E/dalvikvm(10652): Trying to turn backend registerization off
E/dalvikvm(10652): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
E/dalvikvm(10652): JIT_INFO: We cannot transfer from GP reg to XMM and vice versa
I/dalvikvm(10652): JIT_INFO: Unsupported bytecode if-lt
I/dalvikvm(10652): Could not compile trace for Lcom/southernstars/skysafari/Utility;createTextAtlasInfo, offset 409
I/dalvikvm(10652): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/dalvikvm(10652): JIT_INFO: Issues in trace  Lcom/southernstars/skysafari/Utility;createTextAtlasInfo, offset 409
E/dalvikvm(10652): The following issues were seen:
I/dalvikvm(10652):  Issue: Trace contains bytecode with no implementation
I/dalvikvm(10652):  Issue: Issue registerizing the trace in the backend
E/dalvikvm(10652): Trying to turn backend registerization off
E/dalvikvm(10652): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Anyone have any thoughts about what this means?  We have many thousands of users and this is the first report of something like this.  Is there something fundamentally different about the Galaxy Tab 3?

Comment: There should be a line or two in there somewhere indicating that the app crashed.  Search for the last occurrences of 10652 in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did finally figure this out.  The crash was down in the C library (we have native code in the app).  I still am not sure why it crashed but we changed a sscanf() call and it fixed it.  The old code was doing a %100c to copy a string and we changed it to %100s.  Something about the data being copied beyond the \0 with the %100c was causing the problem (no, all the memory was allocated).

This exact code has been used on many related projects and on many platforms for over a decade without at problem.  I can only guess that Samsung was using a slightly different C-library that was not fully compatible.

Bill

Answer (score 2):

The Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 is one of newer Android Tablets powered by an Intel Atom Z2560.
Whilst most Android apps should work on Intel without a problem you should try this in your dev environment first.

Comment: That helped me in my case. My libraries are compiled for ARM and the Google-Play-market didn't exclude the Intel-based Tab 3 10.1 from downloads :/